Learn Italian vocabulary from Greek and Latin roots
Is there a book similar to "Donald M. Ayers's English Words from Latin and Greek Elements" for the Italian language? I would like to find a book that takes the Greek and Latin roots and systematically shows the words that originated from them in Italian. I appreciate any help!
